# How to check spammyness of a link/url

Tags: web-services, api, spam, spam-prevention

I know that most spams are related with one or more links, so I am wondering if there is any web service which can check the spam-weight/spammyness of a URL. Similar to how Akismet can check the spammyness of text content.

p.s. - I searched in google and couldn't find anything satisfactory :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different URI [DNS-based Blackhole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) (or DNSBL) services available to the public for low volume lookups. Two of the most well-known are [SURBL](http://www.surbl.org/) and [URIBL](http://www.uribl.com/). [PhishTank](http://www.phishtank.com/) (run by OpenDNS) is also worth a look as many of the URLs are categorized and classified along with being listed.